# c# copyto arrays in params

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I have made a function that can extend an arrays value by `1` but

I have an issue where I tried to make the following function:

```
//This is error free and compiles properly
public string[] addindex(string[] Input)
{
    string[] ar2 = new string[Input.Length + 1];
    Input.CopyTo(ar2, 0);
    ar2.SetValue("", Input.Length);
    Input = ar2;
    return Input;
}
```

support more than 1 parameter.

So, I made this:

```
public string[] addindexes(params string[] lists)
{
    string[] ar2;
    for (int x = 0; x < lists.Length; x++)
    {
        ar2 = new string[lists[x].Length + 1];
        lists[x].CopyTo(ar2, 0); //Error here
        ar2.SetValue("", lists[x].Length);
        lists[x] = ar2; //Error here
    }
    return lists;
}
```

It seems like I'm using wrong syntax or something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `params string[] lists` to `params string[][] lists` as you're now passing in an array of arrays. (At least, the *method* sees an array of arrays, even if you pass in multiple separate arrays.)

Similarly you need to change the return type to `string[][]`.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Excellent! I dont know but I guess I should use outs instead of return since I want to assign new values to more than 1 array. But out and params is not able to be used at the same time? So how should I make it return the arrays in params so it can set new lengths to the arrays that was assigned in the params.

Comment: There's no easy way to update a whole load of references like you want. If you have several separate `string[]` variables, you're best off calling your original method multiple times. If you have an _array_ of `string[]`s, then passing the _array_ to your updated method will update the references in the _array_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) method for simpler:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

To extend one more item:

```
 Array.Resize(ref list, list.Length + 1);
 list[list.Length - 1] = string.Empty;
```

To extend more than one 1:

```
 int size = 5;
 Array.Resize(ref list, list.Length + size);

 for (int i = list.Length - size; i < list.Length; i++)
     list[i] = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Simpler, but Im just curious. Doesnt such methods make the program "slower"? I have read about such methods compared to more "customized coding" can differ in avg 2 nanoseconds. Which is a small number but I really want to learn to do things proper.

Comment: @user1789344: well, I have not read this, my consideration is 2 nano is trivial, don't fall into premature optimization. Use this method will make your code simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just use generic [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) in the first place?

```
List<string> Input = new List<string>();
Input.Add("new item");
```

Comment: I dont know why, but for some reason I find arrays etc less demanding compared to lists etc. I used Lua before and there it was only "tables" (arrays). So maybe it´s just a logic I have to change? However I find arrays closer to the "source code" and therefore I can develope higher understanding and problem solving by using arrays?

Comment: You can convert list to array and vice versa. There is only few special cases where arrays are better then lists. Besides behind the scenes array is still used, but that is abstracted away from the developer. If you want to "invent a bike" every time you can, I'm just saying that it is not efficient.